# Problema com geração de tabelas (tutorial algaworks)

Tags: java, java-ee, hibernate, jpa

Estou lendo o livro Java EE 7, com JSF, primefaces e CDI. Cheguei na parte de configuração do hibernate, mas estou tendo problemas. Eu configurei minha aplicação em um ambiente J2EE, com JSF e etc e usando o WildFly como Servidor. Após configurar o arquivo persistence.xml e criar o mapeamento de minhas classes, estou tendo problema ao tentar o gerar a database, usando aquela classe com o método main:

```
import javax.persistence.Persistence;

public class CriaTabelas {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
     Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("FinanceiroPU");
    }
}
```

Ao rodar esta classe como um programa JavaSE estou recebendo o seguinte erro:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named OCPQuizPU
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:61)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:39)
    at br.com.alexpfx.ocpquiz.faces.domain.Main.main(Main.java:11)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
```

Até [postei uma pergunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35329691/no-persistence-provider-for-entitymanager-named) no StackOverflow em inglês perguntando sobre isso. Lá também postei toda a configuração da minha aplicação.

Então um dos participantes do fórum me perguntou porque estou rodando uma aplicação JavaSE dentro de uma aplicação JavaEE. Eu também suspeitei que não haveria como essa classe obter as configurações do pom.xml e  do hibernate. No livro não deixa claro como rodar aquela classe (no caso do Livro a classe CriarTabelas, no meu caso a classe Main). Eu pressupus que ela seria rodada como aplicação JavaSE normal, já que ela parte de um método Main... Mas ao que parece eu tenho que alterar o esquema de configuração ou até mesmo criar um projeto Java SE apenas para gerar o database.

---

EDIT

Problema resolvido: no meu caso era um erro no nome da minha Persistence United. Depois deste problema e outros problemas de mapeamento a geração de tabelas usando a classe main funcionou sem problemas.

Comment: Resolveu o problema?

Comment: @WeslleyTavares, Sim, era um simples erro de digitação no nome da minha Persistence Unit.